# Get data from 3 table that are relate to one table with haMany relation

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have one products table and three other table(voltage,ampere,category), now products table is relate all these three table with one to many relation like `voltage,ampere,category hasMany Products` and `Products belongsTo voltage,ampere,category` and each table id is use as foreign key in product table like `products_table : id,name,voltage_id,ampere_id,category_id` .Now how to get all the data from these table and show it in html table of products.

Product Model

```
 public function ampere(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Ampere');
}
 public function category(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
}
 public function voltage(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Voltage');
}
```

Ampere Model

```
public function products(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Product');
}
```

Category Model

```
 public function brands(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Brand');
}
public function products(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Product');
}
```

Voltage Model

```
public function products(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Product');
}
```

Here is my blade view

```
<tr>
  <td class="details">
    a href="#">Product name</a>
   <ul>
      <li><span>category</span></li>
      <li><span>Ampere</span></li>
      <li><span>Voltage</span></li>
    </ul>
   </td>
</tr>
```

this is what I already have tried

```
public function showAllProducts(){
    $products=Product::all();
    $products = Product::with('category','ampere','voltage')->get();

    foreach ($products as $product){
        echo $product->name." ";
        foreach ($product->ampere as $amp){
            echo $amp->name;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you should send the $products data to your view, and then you could use the blade sintax, `$product->ampere->name' this should work

Comment: i will use the blade syntax. but i cannot get the desire data.

Answer (score 2):

when loading multiple relationships using with, you must pass an array:

```php
$products = Product::with(['category','ampere','voltage'])->get();
```

then you can directly use $product->category->name for example.

another thing that I've noticed is that you are using echo in your `showAllProducts` which will not work. what you need to do it to call the view function and pass the $products using the with function.

```php
public function showAllProducts()
{
  $products = Product::with(['category','ampere','voltage'])->get();
  return view("the_name_of_your_view_file")->with("products,$products);
}
```

now, on your view, thanks to blade we can loop on the `$products` array and show every product along with his amper, voltage and category.

```php
@for ( $products as $product )
<tr>
  <td class="details">
    <a href="#">{{$product->name}}</a>
   <ul>
      <li><span>{{$product->category->name}}</span></li>
      <li><span>{{$product->ampere->name}}</span></li>
      <li><span>{{$product->voltage->name}}</span></li>
    </ul>
   </td>
</tr>
@endfor
```

Comment: *"[...] you **must** pass an array "* That's not correct. If you pass multiple parameters, like `'category','ampere','voltage'`, it'll convert it as required. I prefer array syntax, but both are valid.

Comment: ahh didn't know that, so the error would be with the view

Comment: Well, considering the original code isn't actually passing it to the view, there isn't really an error. But yeah, your code looks correct, aside from the possibility of `$product->{whatever}` being null and encountering a `Trying to get property name of non-object`. But that's a separate issue altogether.

Comment: And the fact that in the original code, they're trying to do `foreach($product->ampere as $amp)` This is also incorrect as each product only has 1 `ampere` model, so `$amp->name` is another error. `$amp` would be the value of each column in the database, and `string`s don't have properties.

Comment: yes, and he didn't use blade templates too, not even a loop, maybe he is still a newbie to laravel

Comment: @TimLewis, i return $products and it shows each and every data in array of these table, there is no `$product->{whatever}` is null, but yes im getting the error `Trying to get property name of non-object ` on `product->ampere->name`.

Comment: @DjellalMohamedAniss, yes im newbie to laravel :). and about view, first i check the data by returning it in fuction when the data is correct then i pass it to the view :) i think its a good prectice. what do you say?

Comment: I'm obviously not telling you to actually type `$product->{whatever}`; its a placeholder... You replace `{whatever}` with one of `category`, `ampere` or `voltage`. And since you're getting that error, my statement is correct. You need to check if they existing before trying to access: `$product->ampere ? $product->ampere->name : "No Ampere..."`, or using relationship existence querying: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence